# C++, how base object downcast to derived object?

Tags: c++

Question about **downcast** from base class to derived class, following the example:

with (2)(3)(4), help to explain the difference between **pointer** and **reference** futher?

with (3), how to explain the error information given by g++;

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

int main ()
{
    // example (1)
    Derived d;
    Base* b = &d; // its ok, implict

    // example (2)
    Derived d;
    Base* b = &d;
    Derived* d2 = (Derived*)b; // its ok!

    // example (3)
    Derived d;
    Base& b_ref = d; // its ok, implict
    Derived& d_ref1 = (Derived)b_ref; // error, error: no matching function for call to `Drievd::Drievd(Base&)'

    // example (4)
    Derived& d_ref2 = *((Derived*)(&b_ref)); // its ok
}
```

Comment: "Question about downcast from derived class to super class"

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for reminding, its my fault!

Comment: example 3 should be `Derived& d_ref1 = (Derived&)b_ref;` to match the earlier pattern

Comment: You should edit your code ; as posted example 2 fails because `d` was already declared in example 1. Either use different functions, or different variable names

Comment: Why are you not using `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: I'm a newcomer in c++, I'm  not familiar dynamic_cast. Besides, I want to know more about reference through this example.

Comment: @Jcppython - References go further than just this example.

Comment: When in any doubt, never use C style casts in C++. When casting classes, never use C style casts in C++. Even for obvious cases, only use C style casts if you're lazy and don't mind writing risky code. Instead, use `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` (and know what you are doing when casting). In extreme cases you may need `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, but those are easy ways to get into trouble unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// example (2)
Derived d;
Base* b = &d;
Derived* d2 = (Derived*)b; // its ok!
```

B is a pointer to a `Base`, you can explicitly cast it to a pointer to a `Derived`, so long as it's actually the correct type. Since a C-style cast doesn't do a `dynamic_cast` as part of its [attempted conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), you shouldn't do a C-style cast if there's a chance of failure and your classes are actually polymorphic.

```
// example (3)
Derived d;
Base& b_ref = d; // its ok, implict
Derived& d_ref1 = (Base)b_ref; // error, error: no matching function for call to `Drievd::Drievd(Base&)'
```

You aren't casting to a reference, `(Base)b_ref` creates a new temporary `Base` object by copying the relevant parts which are referred to by `b_ref`. The error is because you can't bind a `Derived` reference to a `Base` without a cast, so the compiler tries to create a temporary `Derived` object, but there is no such constructor on `Derived`. Even if there was such a constructor, it still won't work since the lvalue reference you define is non-const, and cannot bind to a temporary object.

```
// example (4)
Derived& d_ref2 = *((Derived*)(&b_ref)); // its ok
```

This works the same as example (2), except you also dereference the newly converted pointer value, thus obtaining an lvalue reference to a `Derived` object, which happily binds to `d_ref2`

Comment: Not sure what point you are trying to make in the sentence "Since a C-style cast". The C-style cast is identical to a `static_cast` in this context, and a `dynamic_cast` would fail to compile (non-polymorphic type)

Comment: @M.M - Huh? From the OP `class Derived : public Base {};`

Comment: @M.M - And casting a pointer to `Base` into a pointer to `Derived` with a dynamic cast will fail to compile? I don't follow your point

Comment: @M.M - Right, so I overlooked the non-existent virtual function. Still, you could have just said it.

Comment: I did say it in my first comment... ("non-polymorphic type")

Comment: sorry, example(3)(4) should be (Derievd), its my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In example 3, you are trying to cast from a base class object to a derived class object. The compiler is complaining because you do not have a constructor defined in Derived that would let you do something like that. The compiler does not provide a constructor like this for free. This is usually not a valid case, but might be in some unique cases, although not a recommended practice. You can get around the compiler error by using a static_cast, but you might face unexpected runtime errors if you try to use something available in Derived but not in Base.